# Browse and upload file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, file-browser

I have a ASP.NET (.NET Framework 3.5) Application. Now, I have to place a Button on a aspx-Page with the fallowing functionality on click:

- Ask the user for a file with Extension xls (OpenFileDialog)
- Upload the selected file to a specific folder on the WebServer

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a nice component to do some upload with ajax and progress information: http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/asp-net-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery-file-upload-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that can be used for file upload after checking certain file types.

```
  protected void Upload_File() {
    bool correctExtension = false;

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile) {
        string fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
        string[] extensionsAllowed = {".xls", ".docx", ".txt"};

        for (int i = 0; i < extensionsAllowed.Length; i++) {
            if (fileExtension == extensionsAllowed[i]) {
                correctExtension = true;
            }
        }

        if (correctExtension) {
            try {
                string fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath + fileName);
                Label1.Text = "File successfully uploaded";
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Label1.Text = "Unable to upload file";
            }
        }
        else {
            Label1.Text = "File extension " + fileExtension + " is not allowed";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the ASP.NET [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control. Here is a pretty good [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET) on how to complete this task.